# AWS Quicksight : How to disable [ALL] value from control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

[image: Image with ALL option]

I'm using quicksight for analysis. But I want to make sure [ALL] option is disabled. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Click edit controls and select checkbox with "Hide [All] options".